# WP - wp_rewrite page 404

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, permalinks, slug

Change permalink with $wp_rewrite if page is using certain page-theme.

Results in a **404** error in front page and it works fine in admin page.

```
//Change permalink to subject
function change_permalink_themebasis( $post ) {
    $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template' ,true );
    if ( 'page-branches.php' == $template) {
        global $wp_rewrite; 
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . 'branches/%pagename%/'; 
    } elseif ( 'page-modules.php' == $template) {
        global $wp_rewrite; 
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . 'modules/%pagename%/'; 
    } else{
        global $wp_rewrite; 
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . '%pagename%/'; 
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', 'change_permalink_themebasis' );
```

How to fix this? I think the problem is the add_action type "add_meta_boxes_page" but I can't find the proper one.

**EDIT:**
Oke found out it's something with the following code:

```
$wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . 'branches/%pagename%/';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go to **Settings -> Permalinks**, scroll to the bottom and and click **Save Changes**.

Comment: Clarification is king when writing an instructional answer - perhaps explain why this works?

Comment: Yeh, that doesn't work. Normaly that does work because on save it rewrites the .htaccess. But with this script it aint. luckely its 2017 and I fixed the question back in 2015.. (don't remember how) thanks for the comment tho.